# Should You Update Meta Tags in a PWA

Tags: angular, meta

I have a PWA and I inject a whole bunch of meta tags on the server side before serving the initial page. The meta/opengraph/json+ld tags are different on every page.

My question is... is there any benefit to updating the meta tags as the user navigates the application since they won't be doing anymore HTML requests - it'll be all AJAX at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have to update those.

You can update the meta tags or title by importing Meta, Title from @angular/platform-browser.

Import both meta and title in the component:

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

DI in constructor

```
constructor(
    private _meta: Meta,
    private _title: Title
)
{}
```

After collecting the data from web service you can update meta tags and title using below code.

```
private setMetaTitle(type: string) {
       this._meta.updateTag({
         name: 'description',
         content: 'the dynamic description'
       });
       this._title.setTitle('Dynamic title');
   }
```

You can update all the meta tags like this.